# Program for password strength not working

Tags: c, for-loop, passwords

I am a beginner in C.

I have a program to check password strength. A working code snippet from the full program that replicates the problem is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char password [25] = "qwerty1234";
    int counter;
    int numberBool = 0;

    for (counter = 0; counter > 25; counter++)
    {
        if(isdigit(password[counter]))
        {
            numberBool = 1;
        }
    }

    if(numberBool==1)
    {
        printf("You're good to go! \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You're password is not secure \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output of the program is: `"You're good to go!"`

The output I am getting is: `"You're password is not secure"`

I thought the problem was in the FOR loop which was designed to check each character for a digit but is buggy and is not checking each character.

To check whether that conclusion was correct I switched the variable `password` to `1234qwerty` from the original `qwerty1234`. Same output.

Next I tried to change the variable `password` to `1234`. Still the same output.

Even after the above checks I still feel the FOR loop is faulty. However, I cannot get a grasp of whats going wrong.

Comment: Please note that this code contains a logic error in addition to the typo (`>` instead of `<`) that caused the original problem.

Comment: @DavidBowling noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your for loop `for (counter = 0; counter > 25; counter++)` never ran because your counter starts from 0 but your loop condition is counter > 25. Just change it to `for (counter = 0; counter < 25; counter++)`

Comment: @MythicCocoa You have provided a [mcve]. Your question is 100% legit. This is no reason to downvote just because this is a trivial error.

Answer (score 1):

Just see your for loop buddy the statement should be 
There is a small mistake

```
for (counter = 0; counter < 25; counter++) {
  //your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, you need to change your loop condition. But, as it is now, you are testing past the end of the password. You need to use `strlen()` to find the length of the password, and only test these characters:

```
...
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char password [25] = "qwerty1234";
    int counter, pass_len;
    int numberBool = 0;

    pass_len = strlen(password);
    for (counter = 0; counter < pass_len; counter++)
    ...
```